# Is the mask in attention doing the same job as positional encoding?

Tags: nlp, transformer-model, gpt-2

I am new to transformer decoder and confused about the mask in attention. It seems to mask all the words before a particular word. If that is what it does, then is it making the network position-aware, so that positional encoding is no more needed?

Because let's assume no positional encoder. Consider inputs "I am good" and "am I good". Let's say after the processing of the first decoder, the "I" will become the vector x, "am" will become y, "good" will become z. The z of these two input sequences will be exactly the same. But, x and y will be completely different because of the mask in decoder. Then when x, y, z as the inputs of the second decoder, the output of z will be different between these two sequences because x and y are different. So the whole network is actually position-aware.

Am I missing something?

I tried read papers but haven't figure it out, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The positional encoding is introduced in the Transformer to provide information about the positions of tokens in the input sequence. Since the Transformer processes inputs in parallel, it lacks inherent knowledge of the order of tokens. Positional encoding helps the model understand the sequential relationships between different positions.

The attention mask in the Transformer decoder ensures that during the self-attention mechanism, each position can only attend to positions before it in the sequence. This is crucial for maintaining the autoregressive property during training. Without the mask, the model would have access to information from future positions, which would lead to data leakage and incorrect training.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Luis.  I want to ask does the mask still exist when the network is in "predict" mode, instead of "training" mode?

Comment: Technically yes. The model receives N number of tokens each time. For example, if your model has a context window of 256 tokens, it will always receive as input a vector with 256 values. During inference, you can provide it with a partial sequence, for instance, the first 3 tokens. The attention mechanism uses an attention mask that initially allows the model to attend only to the provided tokens and masks out the positions in the future.

Comment: As the model generates new tokens, the attention mask is adjusted, gradually revealing more context by allowing the model to attend to the previously generated tokens along with the new one. This process repeats until the end-of-sequence token is obtained or another stopping condition is met.

Comment: I say technically because in this case nothing is being masked, the model simply needs a vector of fixed size as input and the "masking" allows us to tell it to only pay attention to the tokens that do contain values either given as initial input or those generated by the model itself.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, Luis. Can I ask one more question:  if the positional encoding is simply removed from such pretrained models,  will those models output the same prediction for the prompts  "am I good" and "I am good"? Thank you for your patience~~

Comment: It is clear that this greatly affects the performance of the model. But if it is a pre-trained model, the rest of the layers would have the positions of the tokens encoded in some way. During training the subsequent layers have learned representations that are conditioned on the positional information provided by the encoding during training. Therefore, even if positional coding is removed during inference, the model could still differentiate between "am I good" and "I am good." It also depends on other factors such as model size and the task for which it was initially trained.

Comment: Maybe for classification tasks there is not a big difference in the position of the tokens, depending on the classes. But for text generation tasks, order is important and the model is more likely to adjust the rest of the layers taking into account the information obtained by the positional encoder.